# Single Development for Blackberry and Nokia Java enabled device with J2ME

Tags: netbeans, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor, resource-editor

I have 1+ years development with iOS and now looking for work with Blackberry and Nokia Java enabled devices. Just started work with Netbeans 7.1 IDE with LWUIT.

#### Issue

1. Can I Use the file created by Resource Editor (`ect.res`) in both projects?
   if Yes - then please provide some information.
   if No  - then is there any way for this and which one should be better?
2. I created one file with Resource Editor (`etc.res`) then how I can use this resource file with Netbeans in my project? Because after adding the file project showing same as it was without adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the same res file to both platforms using lwuit in both apps. Be carefull in BB with the http connections, they need some parameters more than j2me normal app.

To use the res file from the code tou will need to open the res using the `Resource` object
To do that:

```
Resources res = Resources.open("path of your res");
```

later you can use many things of your resource (Containers, fonts, localization...)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use for some projects. When you build the project the res file write into binary code that save in dist file. but you need to add the files to project. In my lwuit projects is added under source packages or Resources and is working.

```
 Resources defaultTheme = Resources.open(DEFAULT_THEME_NAME);
```